# Looking for an upper bound for $ \frac{ax - by}{x - y} $

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

I am studying the uniqueness of solution for some ODE that showed in my research. For that I want to use Gronwall's lemma, but it all boils down to finding an upper bound $C$:

$$ \lvert ax - by \rvert \leq C \lvert x - y \rvert$$

Where $x,y$ are both strictly positive  (and bounded actually) and $a,b \in [\epsilon, M]$ for some positive $\epsilon$.

So far, I have narrowed the problem to finding a bound for

$$ \lvert ax - by \rvert = \lvert a(x-y)+y(a-b)  \rvert $$

but I really need the $(x-y)$ factor. Any ideas on how to move forward (or of an alternative approach) are welcome

Comment: You cannot have such a bound unless $a=b$.

Comment: If $a, b$ are distinct, by letting $x\rightarrow y$, we see that $\frac{ax-by}{x-y}\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: If $b > a$ then we can say that $ax-by \leq bx - by = b(x-y)$. Could go along this line?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I think I will mix all the ideas. When $x=y$ I Can use it as a special case and then it is a symetric problem.